# Display a representation of a Word Doc in the browser

Tags: files

Or, how could I embed JPG/PNG representation of Word Doc's first page in the browser window?

I've a client who requested to display an uploaded Word Docs (form a File Field) to the browser. Might there be a way to create an PDF or JPG of the first page of a word document to stand in it's place?

Or, might there be a module or recipe that has covered this type of request?

*Background*: The Word Docs are internally created and *not* uploaded from the general user base. So I'm not worried about content from hundreds of users. It's internal documents that are available for download anyways. They would just like a visual cue to help users more quickly find what's needed.

**Update:** As suggested from a comment, I'm expanding my search [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). I'll update as I stumble upon any potential answers.

- Using [Unoconv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469198) - this may work but I don't want the overhead of running a full office suite on a web server.

Though I'm still holding out for a community based solution.

Comment: You'll need to look elsewhere for a more general php solution. I'd try conversion to PDF as an intermediate step. Possibly try a headless libreoffice wrapper or the Zend PDF lib. Keep the community in mind if you do get something to work and post back here or add to contrib.

Comment: Okay, I'll expand to SO, referencing back this question.